# Django models TextField/CharField: Remove null characters

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a view that takes, in many parts, data from a, let's say, untrusted source, and I want to save the data in a Django model's `TextField`. The input may have null characters, and, if I understand correctly, Postgres (the backend of my project) prohibits saving null characters in the database. I could use `str.replace` to replace the null characters, but I would have to riddle my codebase with `str.replace`, since I have many points where I create models out of the untrusted data. Is there a way to force the cleaning of the data in the model level? I mean, so that I could do `my_model.save()` and in a unique place in my code have `str.replace`, instead of having it in all the places I have a `TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing a post save signal, in the following way:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save

This is an example implementation:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    # ... fields here

# method for your validations
@receiver(post_save, sender=SampleModel)
def validate_input(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     # your custom validations
     instance.save()
```